# audio cannot ready audio 'property' undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have this audio tag in my html

```
<!-- audio -->
    <audio>
    <source src="core/music/error.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="core/music/error.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <!-- end of audio -->
</audio>
```

and then this script that pause the audio

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
audio.pause();
```

however I get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined". Any ideas or clues what's wrong with the code above?

Comment: Move the script to the end of the `body` tag.

Comment: I agree with Vohuman **or** you can place your event listeners in `window.onload=function(){//Here}`

Comment: @Vohuman: quick and gold. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the element is not added to the DOM yet, so the `getElementsByTagName` can't find the target `audio` element. You can either move  the script to the end of the `body` tag or listen to the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    audio.pause();
});
```